# Picking a random audio file in Javascript (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension that will play a random audio clip when clicked. I know how to play a single audio clip, and this is what my `audio.js` file looks like:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var myAudio = new Audio();
    myAudio.src = "clip.mp3";
    myAudio.play();
});
```

However, I would like to play from a variety of audio clips that are in a folder called "clips" (which is inside the main extension folder).

I should also include what my `manifest.json` looks like:

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension Name",
  "description": "Describing Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["hitmark.png"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_title": "TITLE"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["audio.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

The file that I want to be able to access a random clip from is `audio.js`. Inside the "clips" folder, all of the .mp3 files that I want to be randomly selected are numerically ordered 1-7 (ie. "1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, etc"). Can anyone help me select one of these in the `audio.js` file to play at random?

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is the function you're looking for. You can use it to generate a number between 0 and 1 (including 0, but not 1).

Just generate a number, multiply it by however many files there are, then round it down and add one. You will have to tell your code how many files there are, but that'll be it!

```
var AUDIO_CLIPS = 7;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var myAudio = new Audio();
    myAudio.src = (Math.floor(Math.random() * AUDIO_CLIPS) + 1) + ".mp3";
    myAudio.play();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this problem! Now whenever I click a button, Donal Trump will say "China". I finished the extension, you can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5P7r1yRKAnCaXRkNmxfOVYxMjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `Now whenever I click a button, Donal Trump will say "China".` - that isn't random, that's the same thing every time

Comment: It's different clips of him saying china. It's pretty amusing to listen to, imo.